# Discord.js collection; how to navigate and grab/count objects from an array in a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js `Collection` as shown here:
[image]

```js
Collection(1) [Map] {
  '403547647215927306' => {
    dispatcher: StreamDispatcher {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      player: [AudioPlayer],
      streamOptions: [Object],
      streams: [Object],
      _nonce: 2369,
      _nonceBuffer: <Buffer 00 00 09 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
      pausedSince: null,
      _writeCallback: [Function (anonymous)],
      broadcast: undefined,
      _pausedTime: 0,
      _silentPausedTime: 0,
      count: 2369,
      startTime: 1588923698004,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    queue: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    connection: null,
    position: 0
  }
}
```

I want to separate and count the number of dispatcher(s) and the number of objects in the queue(s). I have been able to grab the #dispatcher(s) using

```js
var playlistCount = client.playlists.filter(q => q.dispatcher).size // returns 1 for code, 2 for image
```

But using a similar method

```js
var playlistList = client.playlists.filter(q => q.queue).size // returns 1 for code, 2 for image
```

This should be `3` songs in the queue, not `1` (or `2` in the image) queue active. Could anybody advise how to filter the queue objects to return a size/length/count?

`queue` array if relevant
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find()` to find `queue` and get its `length`

```js
var playlistList = client.playlists.find(playlist => playlist.queue).length
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Trying this I still get [object object] returned 
Image 1 (top half): https://puu.sh/FI85v.png Image 2 (bottom half): https://puu.sh/FI89k.png

Comment: Really thought the edit would work (I had already tried it after the original) but it still returns undefined.